# Is there a way to handle all the number buttons in one keyboard event instead of doing for each buttons in a calculator?

Tags: c#, calculator

Instead of copying and pasting for each number is there a method that could reference to all buttons?

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D5)
            {
                Five.PerformClick(); 
                    
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D5)
            {
                Five.PerformClick();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The answer is yes.  But without seeing more of your code it is not clear why how to do it is not clear to you

Comment: What is the advantage of a master handler method if it is filled with a long if/else blockette to break out each digit and each operator from the others???

Comment: Notice that the first parameter to your handler is `object sender`. That will contain a reference to the object which raised the event. To can have a single handler handle events from multiple objects. BTW, generally if you are writing a calculator, you'd normally be handling button click events. If the text in the button is the digit (like `5`), you could write something like `if (sender is Button b) { DoSomethingWith(b.Text); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the enum values `Keys.D0` to `Keys.D9` have sequential integer [values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). You can abuse this knowledge to turn the `KeyCode` directly into an array index.

```cs
var buttons = new Button[] {Zero, One, ... etc ...};
if(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9){
    var index = (int)e.KeyCode - (int)Keys.D0;
    var button = buttons[index];
    button.PerformClick();
}
if(e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9){
    // similar to the above
}
```

Or you could rearrange your code. Create a separate method for doing the work of "user entered a digit". Then call that method from *both* the button click event and form key event.

```cs
private void HandleDigit(int value){
    // todo
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9){
        var value = (int)e.KeyCode - (int)Keys.D0;
        HandleDigit(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and event for the first button and then tie all the calculator buttons to that event, inside the event you know what key (number) is pressed.
Here is a code that could be useful, i only added two buttons to test it and notice when i live the form im releasing handles unsubscribing the events:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CmdButton1.KeyDown += CmdButtonKeyDown;
            CmdButton2.KeyDown += CmdButtonKeyDown;
        }

        private void CmdButtonKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode==Keys.NumPad1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2 )
            MessageBox.Show("KeyPressed is " + e.KeyCode.ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CmdButton1.KeyDown -= CmdButtonKeyDown;
            CmdButton2.KeyDown -= CmdButtonKeyDown;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you an idea -- instead of the code you show something like

```
 Button.PerformClick('5');
```

would do what you want.  Or even

```
 Button.PerformNumberClick(5);
```

and if + is preseed

```
 Button.PerformOperatorClick('+');
```